# System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' error while trying to use Skip method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to implement the paging feature that EF provides. I thought that I only needed to add the simple `Skip()` and `Take()` into my query, but then I get this message:

> Error 4   'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Skip' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Skip(System.Linq.IQueryable, int)' has some invalid arguments    D:\Biblioteker\HourRegistrationApplication\HourRegistrationService\HourRegistrationWCF\Service.cs   190 24  HourRegistrationWCF

I'm not quite sure about what I need to do here? I've googled a bit but didn't find anything useful.

**GetAllCustomers()**

```
public List<CustomerDTO> GetAllCustomers(string take, string skip)
    {
        var custList = new List<CustomerDTO>();
        var list = DAO.TDKanBanInstance.Customer.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
        foreach (var cust in list)
        {
            custList.Add(new CustomerDTO()
            {
                Name = cust.Name
            });
        }
        return custList;
    }
```

**WORKING SOLUTION**

The `take` and `skip` needs to be `int` of course.

```
public List<CustomerDTO> GetAllCustomers(string take, string skip)
    {
        int skipInt = Int32.Parse(skip);
        int takeInt = Int32.Parse(take);
        var custList = new List<CustomerDTO>();
        var list = DAO.TDKanBanInstance.Customer.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Skip(skipInt).Take(takeInt).ToList();
        foreach (var cust in list)
        {
            custList.Add(new CustomerDTO()
            {
                Name = cust.Name
            });
        }
        return custList;
    }
```

Comment: Arguments for `Skip` and `Take` are both `int`, not `string`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arguments of `Skip` and `Take` must be of type `int`, as they indicate the number of elements to skip and take, respectively, not `string` as in the question.

Comment: Just found out. Sorry for wasting any time. Rookie mistake by me :)

Comment: @Detilium If something can be learned, the time is well-spent.